# Android: Get Position from SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I would like to set the position of a spinner item, but the spinner is being populated with a simplecursoradapter with data from a database. I would like to get the current string from the database, then set the spinner to that value. I know that by using an arrayadapter I can get the position from the adapter this way:

```
String myString = queryData.getString(queryData.getColumnIndex("myString"));

//cast to an ArrayAdapter
mySpinnerAdapter adapter = (mySpinnerAdapter) mySpinner.getAdapter(); 
int spinnerPosition = ?

//set the default according to value
mySpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

But is there a way to get the position of an item from a SimpleCursorAdapter? In the past I have always build an array of my spinner data along side the cursoradapter, but this seems like a dirty way of doing it. If its the only way though...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the item by doing this:

```
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
listView1.reclaimViews(views);
for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
{
    View v = views.get(i);
    // Get the view's text value and compare it with your string here
    // If the two strings match, store the position, which is 'i' in this case
    // If your view is a textview, you would do this:
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (tv.getText().toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(textToCompare.toLowerCase()) == 0)
    {
        // Store position here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the position from the SimpleCursorAdapter in order to set a spinners selected item from a database. I can't use the reclaimViews with a spinner object. Is there another method I can use to achieve the same?

Comment: I can't think of any other way to achieve what you want unless you do what your already had said in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Even i face the same problem. After breaking my head for some hours, i found this solution.
I hope it will help you.

```
/// value is column name in DB. take value from                     
final String[] from = new String[] {"value"}; 
/// field in spinner. Put value into (keep "R.id.text1" as it is..)
final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

// Get Database Access Object to interact with DB

DataAccessObject dataAccessObject = new DataAccessObject(context);

final Cursor valueCursor = dataAccessObject.querySpinnerValues();

final SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        context, R.layout.spinner_row_layout, valueCursor,
        from , to );        

// when ever a field is selected in the spinner's "spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener" method will be called 
// and the primary key
// associted with that particular value will be saved into "someFieldPkMap" map or you can choose other collection..or some
// instance variable..
// 
// Note : Here i am fetching two columns fron DB. 
// 1. "_id" Primary key should always be "_id" otherwise it will not work
// 2. "value" which will be displayed in the spinner. this column can be anything. but you need to map it. The way i did eg..

// final String[] from = new String[] {"value"}; /// value is column name in DB. take value from
// final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1}; /// field in spinner. Put value into (keep "R.id.text1" as it is..)
//  
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {           

        valueCursor.moveToPosition(position);                       

        // Get the primary Key associated with the value...  
        // Use "someFieldPkMap" map to get the primary key
        someFieldPkMap.put(fieldName, Integer.parseInt(valueCursor.getString(0)));                          
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
});

spinner.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
```

Comment: I will have to try this and post my results. Thanks!